# Displaying name attribute in <select> tag at tope of menu

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

I'm coding a drop down menu with the  tag. Is there a way with HTML or CSS to put the *name* attribute of the  tag at the top of the menu? So when it's collapsed the *name* is displayed.

So:

```
<select name="animals">
    <option>Dogs</option>
    <option>Cats</option>
</select>
```

Whether the menu is collapsed "animals" is in the window, or if it's expanded the "animals" is at the top.

The `<optgroup>` tag isn't quite what I'm looking for either.

Comment: I am little confused about what you are trying to accomplish.  Do you want the word Animals to appear as the first option no matter if something else was selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done without either:

1) js to retain the value of the drop down, and replace the options with "animals" onchange.

or

2) make a custom drop down.

select elements are one of those unstylable "native" controls. Not a whole lot you can do with 'em besides what they were made to do.

Comment: I had a feeling. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `details` element as per HTML5:

```
<details>
<summary>animals</summary>
<select name="animals">
   <option>Dogs</option>
   <option>Cats</option>
</select>
</details>
```

Browser support is still limited (looks OK on Chrome though), so you may consider JavaScript techniques (there are probably dozens of alternatives for this in different libraries). However, if the fallback (the text “animals” appearing before the dropdown) is acceptable or if you think you can easily style or script it to something acceptable, this is a simple approach.